# React Native: do you ever have to upgrade `project.pbxproj` manually?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, version, downgrade, pbxproj

I'm following the instructions in [rn-diff-purge](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge) on how to downgrade your React Native version, and I'm looking at [this particular set](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/release/0.61.5..release/0.62.2) of differences between two versions. One of the files that has most differences is `project.pbxproj`. I don't know anything about this file. Is it auto-generated? If I'm downgrading my React Native version by manually making all these changes, do I need to do it for `project.pbxproj` too?